# Perissodactylian Cetaceans

Tags: science-based, creature-design, anatomy, alternate-earth, mammals

Perissodactyla is an order of mammals consisting currently of the seventeen species of horses, rhinoceroses and tapirs.  Usually, any clade is connected by a coupling of genetics and physical morphology.

The ancestor of all perissodactyls, even the extinct brontos and indriks, looked a bit more like this:

[image]

This is *Hyopsodus* of the ancient family called the hyopsodontids.  It was likely swift and nimble, living in burrows and perhaps hunting with echolocation like some species of moles still do today.  The hyopsodontid family did not last long--living from the early Paleocene to the Eocene.  But what if they held on a little bit longer, long enough to assume a larger, more otter-like form and taking on an evolutionary path similar to the archaeocetes, the earliest of the true whales?

Back home, whales are confirmed to be artiodactyls, with their closest living relations being hippopotamuses.  But in this alternate Earth, a clade parallel to whales--let's call them "illhveli", for clarity's sake--are perissodactyls.  Using modern perissodactyls as reference, what sorts of anatomical, skeletal or other kinds of morphological differences should I watch out for in an odd-toed cetacean ("illhveli") in comparison to our even-toed cetacean ("whale", "dolphin", "porpoise")?

Comment: basically just whales, there are no real differences that persist all the way to modern whales.

Comment: @John  No one at the Speculative Evolution forum would accept that.

Comment: the time frame involved is huge ans whales have lost all of the features that actually differ between early perissodactyls and artiodactyls. Keep in mind the earliest animal on the whale lineage does not look all that different from  Hyopsodus, they are both basal ungulata/condylarths, anatomically very similar, and closely related, The major difference is size.

Comment: Convergent evolution would simply drive them to the same end points, with minor differences due to occupying different niches. Sharks, Dolphins and Ichthyosaurs are very similar in form and lifestyle despite vastly different ancestors. Unless the Cetaceans drive them out of the marine niche, in which case they evolve to fill a different niche

Comment: @Thucydides Presumably they all have exactly the same ancestor, just like the rest of us.

Comment: @DrMcCleod: Yes, they have a distant common ancestor. But their more recent ancestors were very different from one another, and yet the descendants evolved to be superficially similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no predicted difference, so any difference is up to you.

*Hyopsodus* is [very close](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-new-apheliscine-%22condylarth%22-mammal-from-the-late-Zack-Penkrot/d628f900a3e135b769f30638657c0b7f7ff7861e) to split in condylarths that leads to artidacyles and perrisodacyles, there is little anatomical difference present that is not lost in cetacea. Hyopsodus is smaller but not that much smaller. the ankle structure is different but whales lose that difference. Whales are so derived for aquatic living that they have lost the noticeable anatomical differences.

to put it a different way the differences within existing cetacea is far greater than any difference inherited from that far back, if you want to make it different you can but there is nothing inherited from *Hyopsodus* that will cause it. If you want them to look like otters, or hippo, or walrus you can, you get to decide all the evolutionary path they take.

Comment: It's appreciated, and it's given me something to think.

Comment: Wait what? When has it been definitively demonstrated that Cetartiodactyla and Perissodactyla are sister taxa? That is, is there a consensus that Euungulata is a valid taxon?

Comment: Why would I be referring to Cetartiodactyla, Perissodactyla and Artiodactylamorpha/Artiodacyla  are the sister taxa. https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0007062

Answer (score 1):

We will assume (we have to assume something!) that the basal perissodactyl offered in the OP has in it to potential to evolve into these later forms, because it did.  How to transition to an aquatic form?

Let us consider what perissodactyls do well, judging from modern forms.  They do well as vegetarians, using hindgut fermentation and eating large quantities of low quality fodder.  Larger body size can accommodate this lifestyle better.  Extant perissodactyls are horses, zebras and rhinoceri.

One large bodied semiaquatic mammalian herbivore is the hippopotamus.  Could the aquatic perissodactyl be something like a hippo – a large bodied four legged swimmer,  grazing aquatic grasses and seaweeds?  Yes.  **Behold Desmostylus, the aquatic perissodactyl!**.

[image: Desmostylus images]

From [Bone Inner Structure Suggests Increasing Aquatic Adaptations in Desmostylia (Mammalia, Afrotheria)](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0059146#pone.0059146-Repenning2)

> Figure 1. Various restorations of desmostylians based on morphological
>   data illustrating the diverse lifestyles proposed. A, semi-aquatic
>   (like the polar bear) (from [17]). B, bottom wader (from Inuzuka's
>   restoration; the figure is printed with the permission of the
>   Geological Museum, Geological Survey of Japan). C, bottom
>   walker, Hippopotamus-like (from [73]); D, bottom swimmer,
>   sirenian-like (from [22]). E–F, active swimmer, pinniped-like
>   (from [23]–[24]).

Their aquatic adaptations made it difficult to place desmostylians in a family group.  The most recent cladistics analysis puts them in perissodactyla, and so a cousin to horses (Hippomorphs) and tapirs (Tapiromorphs).

[Anthracobunids from the Middle Eocene of India and Pakistan Are Stem Perissodactyls](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4189980/)

[image: clade]

Different forms of locomotion were proposed for the desmostylians, as shown in the above artists depictions.  As regards how aquatic they were, a recent bone analysis put the desmostylians closer to sirenians and pinnipeds than hippopotami and polar bears.

These researchers (same source as art image) concluded “the bone microanatomical specializations of desmostylians (i.e. bone mass increase and a spongy inner organization) indicate that all desmostylians were probably predominantly, if not exclusively, aquatic.”

---

But the OP did not want an oceangoing hippo.  He wanted a WHALE!  A whale must be provided, or risk a downvote!   How to move from the 4-legged swimmer desmos to something closer to a cetacean?

Let’s take a look at a desmo skeleton, and consider its lifestyle, and then see if nature has any examples we can use as a model for a cetacean-morph perissodactyl.

[image: desmo skeleton]

Depicted: skeleton of the desmostylian Neoparadoxica repenningi.  From [The phylogeny of desmostylians revisited: proposal of new clades based on robust phylogenetic hypotheses](https://peerj.com/articles/7430/#fig-3)

Those hind legs are already close together.  As the creature gets larger and rare expeditions to the land become more a dragging than a walking  those will probably fuse into a propulsive apparatus like a seal or a manatee.   And manatees, or more properly sirenians, is where we will get the model for the whale-like perissodactyl:  **Steller's sea cow**.

[image: stellers sea cow]
http://lostzoo.com/animals/001_stellersseacow1_eng.html

Steller's sea cow was an immense relative of the manatee, growing to 10 meters long.  They lived in the Pacific and ate kelp.  They are famous for being huge, tasty and also going extinct almost immediately after they were discovered.

It is proposed that the desmostylians went extinct because they were outcompeted by sirenians like the sea cow.  Their lifestyles seem very similar and they were structurally similar too with skulls adapted to suctioning up sea plants.

[image: skull morphology coomparison]
https://ocean.si.edu/ocean-life/marine-mammals/flippers-or-feet-extinct-mammal-may-have-been-replaced-todays-sea-cows

Steller's sea cow was whale sized at 10 meters.  Scaling up a desmostylian to that size would mean losing / fusing hind limbs but keeping the feeding style and digestion of the smaller forms that really existed.

Finally: how to distinguish this perissodactyl "cetacean" from extant cetacean  The big difference would be diet.  There are no vegetarian cetaceans.  Distinguishing the illhveli from sirenians would be more difficult.  Maybe tusks?  Desmostylus had tusklike teeth and tapirs have tusks.  Maybe illhveli would retain a tusk?

[image]

https://www.reddit.com/r/Inktober/comments/9no0v6/medieval_whales_for_inktober/

Comment: One--the hyopsodontids weren't herbivores.  Two--the desmostylians were their own order, not perissodactyls.

Comment: One - the hyopsosontids were primitive mammals with as much in common with shrews as with horses.  You were interested in the fact that they were perissodactyls so that (later) aspect of the phenotype is what I emphasized.    Two:  I did not make up the desmostylian cladistics.  If you disagree with the cladistic analysis (linked, and clade image posted) I would be interested to know why.

Comment: Hyopsodontids WERE perissodactyls.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyopsodontidae  SealBoi suggested that to me.  And the desmostylians belonged to the order Desmostylia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desmostylia

Comment: AFAIK, the phylogeny of Desmostylia is still a matter of research. They *might* be nested within the Perissodactyla, or they may be instead nested within the Afrotheria. @JohnWDailey: Orders and other such Linnean ranks don't go well with phylogenetic nomenclature. It is utterly irrelevant that Desmostylia is currently ranked as an order.